# Align pictures evenly in a div box

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to align all the pictures in the box evenly. I want the pictures to have a evenly margin to the border of the box and to each other. The pictures should remain their ratio, no matter the screen size. But they should shrink and expand in general with smaller and bigger screens and try to fill out the box.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

```css
.h {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.chars {
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
  height: 40%;
  background-color: goldenrod;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="chars">

  <img class="h" src="images/Mage.png" />
  <img class="h" src="images/Mage.png" />
  <img class="h" src="images/Mage.png" />
  <img class="h" src="images/Mage.png" />
  <img class="h" src="images/Warrior.png" />
  <img class="h" src="images/Mage.png" />
  <img class="h" src="images/Mage.png" />
  <img class="h" src="images/Mage.png" />
  <img class="h" src="images/Mage.png" />
  <img class="h" src="images/Mage.png" />

</div>
```

Comment: you might need : `justify-content:space-between;` but i do not understand the point of your `.h{/*rules*/}` . Can youset up a snippet or a jsfiddle/codepen with image (can be fake from lorempixel.com or dummyimage.com) to see what you tryed so far . here we have no idea of ratio and image's sizes

Comment: There is not really a point for it. It is just a placeholder.

Comment: A placeholder ? i see these are img in your HTML ?!?

Comment: Could you let me know what is not working with the answer a gave, so I will be able to adjust and you to accept?

Answer (score 1):

Use `justify-content: space-around` to distribute them evenly and `calc(10% - 6px)` + `padding: 0 3px` to make them responsive and keep equal space between themselves and their parent's edge

```css
.h {
  align-self: center;
  width: calc(10% - 6px);
}
.chars {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 50%;
  height: 40%;
  background-color: goldenrod;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 25%;
  padding: 0 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="chars">

  <img class="h" src="http://placehold.it/50" />
  <img class="h" src="http://placehold.it/50" />
  <img class="h" src="http://placehold.it/50" />
  <img class="h" src="http://placehold.it/50" />
  <img class="h" src="http://placehold.it/50/f00" />

  <img class="h" src="http://placehold.it/50" />
  <img class="h" src="http://placehold.it/50" />
  <img class="h" src="http://placehold.it/50" />
  <img class="h" src="http://placehold.it/50" />
  <img class="h" src="http://placehold.it/50" />

</div>
```

With the given setup, using `div` and `background-image` is another option, that might be better if you don't know the amount of *images* and their ratio

```css
.h {
  margin: 0 3px;
  flex: 1;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat:  no-repeat;
}
.chars {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 50%;
  height: 20%;
  background-color: goldenrod;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 25%;
  padding: 0 3px;
}
.chars + .chars {
  top: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="chars">

  <div class="h" 
       style="background-image: url(http://placehold.it/50)"></div>
  <div class="h" 
       style="background-image: url(http://placehold.it/50)"></div>
  <div class="h" 
       style="background-image: url(http://placehold.it/50)"></div>
  <div class="h" 
       style="background-image: url(http://placehold.it/50)"></div>
  <div class="h" 
       style="background-image: url(http://placehold.it/100x50/f00)"></div>

  <div class="h" 
       style="background-image: url(http://placehold.it/50)"></div>
  <div class="h" 
       style="background-image: url(http://placehold.it/50)"></div>
  <div class="h" 
       style="background-image: url(http://placehold.it/50)"></div>
  <div class="h" 
       style="background-image: url(http://placehold.it/50)"></div>

</div>

<div class="chars">

  <div class="h" 
       style="background-image: url(http://placehold.it/50)"></div>
  <div class="h" 
       style="background-image: url(http://placehold.it/50)"></div>
  <div class="h" 
       style="background-image: url(http://placehold.it/50)"></div>
  <div class="h" 
       style="background-image: url(http://placehold.it/50)"></div>
  <div class="h" 
       style="background-image: url(http://placehold.it/50)"></div>
  <div class="h" 
       style="background-image: url(http://placehold.it/50x100/f00)"></div>

  <div class="h" 
       style="background-image: url(http://placehold.it/50)"></div>
  <div class="h" 
       style="background-image: url(http://placehold.it/50)"></div>
  <div class="h" 
       style="background-image: url(http://placehold.it/50)"></div>
  <div class="h" 
       style="background-image: url(http://placehold.it/50)"></div>
  <div class="h" 
       style="background-image: url(http://placehold.it/50)"></div>

</div>
```

---

Updated with this extra sample based on a comment, where the images should be in 2 lines

```css
.h {
  align-self: center;
  width: calc(20% - 6px);
  margin: 3px 0;
}
.chars {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: goldenrod;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 25%;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="chars">

  <img class="h" src="http://placehold.it/50" />
  <img class="h" src="http://placehold.it/50" />
  <img class="h" src="http://placehold.it/50" />
  <img class="h" src="http://placehold.it/50" />
  <img class="h" src="http://placehold.it/50/f00" />

  <img class="h" src="http://placehold.it/50" />
  <img class="h" src="http://placehold.it/50" />
  <img class="h" src="http://placehold.it/50" />
  <img class="h" src="http://placehold.it/50" />
  <img class="h" src="http://placehold.it/50" />

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. That is already pretty cool. But I want the images to fill out the whole box. Basically I want two lines of Images, 5 images per line. With a small margin between images and box.

Comment: @Alter I update my answer adding yet another sample. Also, it is good for future users to know which answer solved a question, including yourself, so please go through your answers and accept the one that best solved each. If some didn't, notify the answerer so they can adjust so it does.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest leveraging `background-image` instead of inserting images, as you can use `background-size` to help with maintaining scaling ratios.

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/p4fdyq6e/2/)**

**CSS**

```
.chars {
    width: 50%;
    height: 40%;
    background-color: goldenrod;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    left: 25%;
    display:table;
    border-collapse:separate;
    border-spacing:3px; // use this to space out items
}
.char{
    width:1%; // this is to create a 'justified' alignment of the 'cell's
    display:table-cell;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center center;
    background-size:contain;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="chars">
    <div class="char" style="background-image:url('http://lorempixel.com/400/800/');"></div>
    <div class="char" style="background-image:url('http://lorempixel.com/400/800/');"></div>
    <div class="char" style="background-image:url('http://lorempixel.com/400/800/');"></div>
    <div class="char" style="background-image:url('http://lorempixel.com/400/800/');"></div>
    <div class="char" style="background-image:url('http://lorempixel.com/400/800/');"></div>
    <div class="char" style="background-image:url('http://lorempixel.com/400/800/');"></div>
    <div class="char" style="background-image:url('http://lorempixel.com/400/800/');"></div>
    <div class="char" style="background-image:url('http://lorempixel.com/400/800/');"></div>
    <div class="char" style="background-image:url('http://lorempixel.com/400/800/');"></div>
</div>
```